# How to change drush.php to drush as an alias on windows 10?

Tags: drupal, drush

I have installed drush launcher & placed .phar file after making it executable but the drush commmand only runs with drush.php.

I also made a bat file with following code but it didn't work.

@echo off
php "%~dp0\drush.phar" %*

Answer (score 0):

In windows configuring drush is little bit tricky. And you need some supporting software to do that. Here's a blog post you can follow, might helpful. 
[Drush on Windows 10/8.1](https://moshiuramit.wordpress.com/2015/11/24/drush-on-windows-108-1/)

Comment: @Drupal WC do you get any solution. Are you able to use drush in windows ?

Comment: I have drush already configured. The issue I faced was to use it as drush not drush.php